# MySQL: Having multiple volleyball set results for the same match

Tags: mysql, database

For school I have to create a database where volleyball match info can be stored. For this I use a table `MATCH` with columns `ID(PK, NN)`, `Date(NN)`, `Time(NN)`, `Playfield(NN)` and then three foreign keys for three teams (`TEAM_ID` for home team, `TEAM_ID1` for away team and `TEAM_ID2` for the team that has to send the referee (all `PK` and `NN`)).

Each volleyball match consists of a number of sets, each of which is scored separately.
For the result info, I have a table `RESULT` with columns `MATCH_ID (= MATCH.ID, PK, NN)`, `SET (NN, UNIQUE)`, `ScoreA` (score for team playing at home), `ScoreB` (score for team playing away), `PointsA` (points for team playing at home), `PointsB` (score for team playing away).

What I want to be able to do, is add results from 4 sets to one `MatchID`. Our teacher told us it would be best to have 4 sets per 1 match, so I guess it's possible. I just can't figure out how.

Could someone help me?

Again, if it's unclear, please say so and I'll try to explain it even more (if I can).

Comment: Don't call it MATCH http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: share sample data and what your expect your result set to be

Comment: Why do you have 3 team IDs for a single match?  Normally, don't you have just two teams playing at a time?

Comment: Two teams for the playing teams, and one for the team that has to send the referee for the match. Sorry for not mentioning that.

@Strawberry Well it's Dutch, I just translated it so you'd understand what I was talking about. The name is WEDDSTRIJD, which is Dutch for MATCH.

Comment: In that case, fine! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Keep your tables like this.

**tbl_matches**

1. ID
2. DateTime_of_play
3. Playfield
4. TEAM_ID
5. TEAM_ID1
6. TEAM_ID2
7. match_winner_teamID

**tbl_sets**

1. ID
2. matchID
3. setNo
4. scoreA
5. scoreB
6. setWinner

You can keep as many rows for 1 match in the `tbl_sets`